# UIView animation only fires when a static image is presented

Tags: ios, image, animation, core-animation, avfoundation

I have a photo taking app that I initially set up so that the picture the user took was shown for three seconds on a UIImageView, then was to be hidden and saved. It worked, but then I decided to change it to have the image move to the right and off the screen, it works but only when I declare `previewImage.image` in the method that the animation is fired in and will only work when I plug in a static image (such as `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];`)instead of the image that is taken from the camera. I can't figure out why this is happening for the life of me! Please help me anyway you can. Here is the code that I am using, please note that I save all the images in another method that saves them in a core-data model:

This is what I use to take the photo:

```
- (IBAction)takeSnapshot:(id)sender {

    // Void all previously declared instances
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;

    // Checks what video connection is currently being used (rear camera)
    // Sets videoConnection to that connection
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in self.captureManager.captureImageOutput.connections)
    {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
        {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo])
            {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection)
            break;
    }

    // Captures the instance recorded from above
    [self.captureManager.captureImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
                                                                    completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
    {

        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        [previewImage setImage:image];
        if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear]) {
            previewImage.image = image;
        } else {
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder"];
        }
        previewImage.hidden = NO;

        if (error != nil) {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:error.localizedDescription
                                        message:error.localizedRecoverySuggestion
                                       delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                              otherButtonTitles:nil]
            show];
        }

    }];

    if (event.title == nil) {
        [self noEventFound];
    } else {
        [self commitImageTakenAnimation];
        [self saveImageToFile];
    }
}

- (void)commitImageTakenAnimation {

    previewImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder"];
    previewImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    // Launch the chain of the bug animation at the bottom of viewDidAppear
    [self moveLeft:nil finished:nil context:nil];
}
```

Below is a little bump that the image does to make it seem more natural:

```
- (void)moveLeft:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0.5
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect previewImageStartMoveFrame = previewImage.frame;
                         previewImageStartMoveFrame.origin.x = -previewImageStartMoveFrame.size.width * .25;
                         [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
                         previewImage.frame = previewImageStartMoveFrame;
                         [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(moveRight:finished:context:)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSLog(@"Move Left Done");
                     }];

}


- (void)moveRight:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

    CGRect previewImageOffScreenFrame = previewImage.frame;
    previewImageOffScreenFrame.origin.x = previewImageOffScreenFrame.size.width * 2;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
                         previewImage.frame = previewImageOffScreenFrame;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         NSLog(@"Face right done");
                         [self saveImageToFile];

                         previewImage.hidden = YES;
                         previewImage.image = nil;
                 }];

}
```

Also, I have noticed that when the animation has been played (again, using only a static image), the completion block never seems to be called, I never get a message in the log, and the `previewImage` is never hidden.

Comment: Could you define the _minimum_ setup to reproduce the error

Comment: Basically, I have an AVCaptureManager that is responsible for showing a live feed of the rear camera. When the user wants to take a photo, they simply press the button on the screen, it calls the `takeSnapshots` method as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you setting an animationDelegate ?  you don't need this with the completion handler block equipped newer animations.  Id remove those and the animationDidStop method and call [self moveRight: etc:] straight from the completion handle block in the first one

Comment: This worked, thanks! One question though, why would setting an animationDelegate block my animation from happening?

Comment: I don't think the animationDelegate was ever being called, because you've used one of the newer animation methods (with blocks), pretty sure the didstop stuff etc is not part of those ones (no longer necessary) so moveRight: was never being called

Comment: Ok, got it. I'm new to UIView animations so I followed [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-uiview-animation) tutorial on raywenderlich.com, but I guess things have changed since then. Thanks for the reply!